# Chktex complains about "no italic correction found", how to fix this?

Tags: amsthm, italic, slanted, italic-correction, chktex

I use the following code for custom theorems, as I like slanted text in thereoms better than italicized, using `amsthm`.

```
\newtheoremstyle{thm-sl}
{}{}
{\slshape}  % slanted text instead of italicized
{}
{\bfseries}
{.}
{.5em}
{}
```

I get a warning from `chktex`:

```
Warning 6 in doc.tex line 21: No italic correction (`\/') found.
{\slshape}  % slanted text instead of italicized  
         ^
```

I understand, that italic correction (`\/`) should be used, to insert some space between italicized/slanted characters and upright characters, appearing directly after another. Though in my case, there should be no characters after the slanted text.

So is this just an overreaction of `chktex` or is there a more "correct" to use `newtheoremstyle`?

Funnily, using `{\slshape\/}` mutes `chktex`, but will not compile, due to the error

```
! You can't use `\/' in vertical mode.
```

Comment: I guess in that case you just don't want to keep `chktex` happy. These automatic tools can't always get everything right.

Comment: Apparently you should be able to silence the warning by adding `% chktex 6` after the `{\slshape}` (haven't tested that).

Comment: I'm not even sure why `chktex` examines things in the preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic syntax checkers or linters don't (and maybe can't) always get everything right.

In this case there is no need for italic correction with `\slshape` since the following text will start in a new line and not directly after the slanted text in the same line. Anyway, it would certainly be inappropriate to add `\/` directly after `\slshape` here since the correction needs to be added at the end of the slanted/italic text (`{\slhape lorem ipsumf\/} dolor` not `{\slshape\/ lorem ipsumf} dolor`). Here the `{\slshape}` is not a group that prints anything, it is the argument of a command that determines the formatting of the theorem later.

You can disable the warning by adding a comment with `checktex 6` in the offending line

```
\newtheoremstyle{thm-sl}
{}{}
{\slshape}% chktex 6
{}
{\bfseries}
{.}
{.5em}
{}
```

See §6.1.4 of the [ChkTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf).

Since you are probably going to use only the `\text...{...}` macros instead of their switches (`\textit`–`\itshape` etc.) in the document you could probably disable the entire warning 6 altogether. The documentation has more hints on that (`-n6` command line option or `chktexrc` config file).